# Locate a href after element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm hoping that you have the answer to my question, i'm using jQuery to addClass to the link right after the "current" element. (link to page 2 in this example). I'm not able to do so with ".pagination > .current > a" etc. Any ideas ?

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="current">1</span> | 
    <span><a href="#">2</a></span> | 
    <span><a href="#">3</a></span> | 
    <span><a href="#">4</a></span> | 
    <span><a href="#">5</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select the `.current` element, then use `next` and `find` to get the `a` element, something like this:

```
$('.current').next().find('a').addClass('foo');
```